# Deleting/Updating List Items in a OneToManyRealtion - Springboot

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to update list item in a oneToMany Relation. I'm getting this error

```
2021-11-10 23:12:58.545  WARN 50875 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction]
```

Structure of my model looks like

```
class A {

    ....

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<B> bs;

    ....

}

class B {

    ....

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    A a;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<C> cs;

    ....

}


class C {

    ....

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    B b;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "c", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<D> ds;

    ....

}

class D {

    ....

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "c_id")
    C c;

    ....

}
```

How would I update value of `List<B> bs`. I tried `deleteAll` from repository, but getting the same error. I tried putting a null value instead and persisting, same error.

Comment: I don't think CascadeType.ALL is a good idea here. https://thorben-janssen.com/avoid-cascadetype-delete-many-assocations/

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace?